# Implementation of Nearby Person on web page

Tags: php, html, google-maps

is there anyone knows how to implement Nearby Person on Web page ? Is it Possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation could be something like this:

```
<?php

$people = 
[
    'John',
    'Adam',
    'Terry',
    'Gary',
    'Wilbur'
];

$get_closest = function ($person) use ($people)
{
    $closest = [];
    $key = array_search($person, $people);
    if($key !== false) {
        $before = $key-1;
        $after  = $key+1;
        if(isset($people[$before]))
            $closest[] = $people[$before];
        if(isset($people[$after]))
            $closest[] = $people[$after];
    }

    return $closest;
};

var_dump($get_closest('Gary'));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Terry"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Wilbur"
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use like Nearby Searching in Web based Like in Android Applications ? I can't find any tutorials or sample .. thanks in advance sir :D

Comment: I am not familiar with nearby searching on Android.   Perhaps try and describe what you are trying to achieve and what you have thought about/done so far.  A very simple approach could be to grab geo-locations from each person, and place them in a grid.  Nearby people could be those in the same block.  Or use that combined with Pythagoras' theorem to work out radial distances from a central point to other people.  If distances are larger look up the haversine formula.